# for every 1 do this code in vb

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I want to make for ever "1" in the text box do this code.

Instead it wont just see if there's any 1's or 2's

I tried this:

```
select case text box    
case "1"    
   'do code    
case "2"    
   'do code        
end select
```

so if i typed 132421
it would not run my code i put for 1 and 2 it has to be just a 1 or a 2 in the text

Comment: This does not make much sense. Are you just for any instance of the number or all instances?

Comment: No idea what you're asking.

Comment: Because when you use `Case` it is looking for whole strings only. For example, `Case "1"` means that the code will only be executed when the whole `string` in the `TextBox` is 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want your code to execute **multiple times** for each occurrence of the digit 1, 2, etc. This loop would accomplish that:

```
For Each digit as Char in MyTextbox.Text
  If digit = "1" Then
    ' do code
  Else If digit = "2"
    ' do code
  End If
Next
```

Comment: thank you it works im sorry for not putting things in enough detail

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want it to run specific code for each instance of those numbers? Like Nate said.

You will need to do a loop to run through each character in the textbox.

```
For Each Letter as Char in Textbox1.Text 
  Select Case Letter
    Case "1"
    ' Do Code
    Case "2"
    ' Do Code
  End Select
Next
```

If you typed 132421, it would loop 6 times, though using only ones and twos only 4 will activate any code in this example.

Comment: I prefer your method, but i thought the user would understand easier if i used as much of their original code as i could.